# Django extract value from dict response

Tags: python, django

I have a model "Drug" that has a child foreign key "Accounting Entry" that contains a quantity.  There are multiple Accounting Entries per drug and I have aggregated the sum of the child quantities to Drug as sumQuantities.

The problem I have now is that when I'm rendering the template I see the following:

> Quantity on Hand 
>   {'Quantity__sum': 11}
>   {'Quantity__sum': 99}
>   {'Quantity__sum': 222}

I'm trying to get the 'Quantity__sum': 11 to display as the basic value (11) but can't seem to get it to function correctly

Thanks very much for any help

models.py

```
class Drug(models.Model):
Facility = models.ForeignKey(Facility, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Name = models.TextField(max_length=120,default='default')

def _get_sum_quantity(self):
    return self.quantities.aggregate(Sum('Quantity'))

sumQuantity = property(_get_sum_quantity)

def __str__(self):
    drug_name = self.Name
    return drug_name

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Drugs'


class AccountingEntry(models.Model):
    Drug = models.ForeignKey(Drug, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quantities')
    Quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

views.py

```
def update(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'update.html'
    return render(request, 'update.html', {'drug_list': Drug.objects.all()})
```

HTML Snippet

```
{% for drug in drug_list %}
    <td>{{ drug.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ drug.sumQuantity }}</td>
    {% if not forloop.last %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these lines

```
{'Quantity__sum': 11}
{'Quantity__sum': 99}
{'Quantity__sum': 222}
```

comes from `drug.sumQuantity` (located inside the HTML snippet. So, if you want to get the value of the Quantity__sum, you can do a dot notation on the SumQuantity property. So, you may have something similar to this

```
{% for drug in drug_list %}
    <td>{{ drug.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ drug.sumQuantity.Quantity__sum }}</td>
    {% if not forloop.last %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This was it exactly, thank you it immediately resolved to the underlying values.  Greatly appreciate your time to answer!

Comment: if this answer si correct, please mark it as correct